# Disable a device/ trackstick with libinput

Tags: xinput, libinput

Since `xinput --disable 7` doesn't work on Ubuntu 17 anymore, I'm looking for a similar solution to disable a trackstick. Gnome settings do not provide any options for this.

I tried a workaround with `sudo evtest --grab /dev/input/event7`, but I'm not confident with that yet.

For your information: evtest --grab device grabs all information sent from the device and blocks any inputs from the device while it runs and logs the movements.

First problem: Since it requires root privileges, I could not write a working bash script in rc.local to run it at boot. Boot will not finish, because rc.local runs all scripts before booting and evtest --grab runs at infinite time, so the booting process didn't finish either.

Second problem: A workaround would be to open a terminal on my own and run evtest --grab. But this would be a spam terminal window and additional steps at every boot, which is pretty annoying.

**So my conclusion is that I need to disable the device directly with libinput, xwayland or anywhere else.**

I appreciate any help. Cya folks.

Edit: My  `xinput list` kind of looks like this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:13                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:13              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:13                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `xinput -list` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 did that.

Comment: Is it 4, 6 or 7 that you want to disable? Doesn't `xinput --disable 7` work at all?

Comment: No, xinput --disable 7 does not work. The listed devices are only virtual abstractions of the libinput/ xwayland configured devices.

Comment: sudo is not possible nor required in /etc/rc.local. I am not quite sure, but you may need something more like: `evtest --grab /dev/input/event7 > /dev/null 2>&1 &` Please try it and we'll try to refine it as needed.

Comment: What does the  > /dev/null 2>&1 & do?

Comment: I think it channels the terminal output away and releases the terminal for the next boot tasks.

Comment: @chili555 You're a boss. It works for me. Device is disabled and booting works, too. Anyways it would be cool, if libinput would offer a more standard way to disable devices, just sayin' :p.

You can post this as answer and I'll accept it.

You really helped me alot, thank you, Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you amend the rc.local line to send the output of evtest to null and release the boot process to continue. I suggest that you try:

```
evtest --grab /dev/input/event7 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: It's sad but this the best option I've found to disable libinput devices without having to write udev rules